# same salt, same password, different results (bcrypt)

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I'm using [bcrypt with Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) and the hash comes out different each time, even using the same salt. This is my code:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

let saltRounds = 1;
let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
let hash = bcrypt.hashSync('senha', salt);

console.log(hash);
```

What am I doing wrong? How to solve this?

Comment: this is standard in bycrpt. an input can generate a different hash. that why you need to check with `bcrypt.compare`

Comment: Could you give an example where you _actually_ use the same salt?

Comment: There is nothing wrong here, this is just how bcrypt works. Can you share some snippets of your use case? I think then your problem will make more sense. Thanks!

Comment: If `genSaltSync` produced the same salt on every call, it would be useless :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are re-generating the salt each time.  You must generate the salt only once, and store it along with the hashed password.  When it comes time to validate, pull the salt and the hashed password from storage, hash the input password using the stored salt, and compare to the stored hashed password.